# Mover imagem dentro de uma picturebox com o mouse sem usar a scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, imagem

Por gentileza, alguém sabe como eu posso movimentar uma imagem dentro de uma `pictureBox` sem precisar clicar na *scrollbar*? O que desejo é movimentar a imagem, apenas clicando com o mouse em cima da mesma de modo a arrastá-la dentro da `pictureBox`.

Esse é o Form:

[image: Form]

Quando clico no botão, ele carrega uma imagem na minha picturebox de acordo com o código abaixo:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.AutoScroll = true;
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C://matrix3.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Cria um mousemove na picture, e neste mousemove, altere o ScrollX e ScrollY do ScrollBar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma possível solução seria usar o evento [MouseMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) de sua PictureBox para aplicar a rolagem de acordo com a **variação de posição** de seu cursor:

```
    // Variáveis globais:
    int posXInicial; // Posição X do mouse ao clicar/se mover sobre a imagem
    int posYInicial; // Posição Y do mouse ao clicar/se mover sobre a imagem

    enum Sentido // Sentido do movimento
    {
        Cima,
        Baixo,
        Direita,
        Esquerda
    }

    private void ScrollImg(int pixels, Sentido sent)
    {
        using (Control ctrl = new Control())
        {
            ctrl.Parent = panel1; // Define o controle pai
            switch (sent)
            {
                case Sentido.Baixo:
                    ctrl.Top = panel1.ClientSize.Height + pixels; // Adiciona pixels à distância do controle até o topo
                    break;
                case Sentido.Cima:
                    ctrl.Top = pixels * -1;
                    break;
                case Sentido.Direita:
                    ctrl.Left = panel1.ClientSize.Width + pixels;
                    break;
                case Sentido.Esquerda:
                    ctrl.Left = pixels * -1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            panel1.ScrollControlIntoView(ctrl); // Aplica a rolagem
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Definindo a posição inicial (em relação à imagem) do mouse a clicar sobre a imagem:
        posXInicial = e.Location.X;
        posYInicial = e.Location.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int pixels = 15; // Número de pixels movidos ao arrastar o mouse sobre a tela

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) // Verifica se o botão esquerdo está pressionado
        {
            /* OBS:
             * Como o evento MouseMove é disparado várias vezes, é necessário
             * verificar se a posição (tanto X quanto Y) do mouse mudou se comparada à última.
             */

            if (posXInicial != e.Location.X) 
            {
                // Ajusta o movimento de acordo com a direção para a qual o mouse está sendo movido:

                if (e.Location.X > posXInicial) 
                {
                    ScrollImg(pixels, Sentido.Direita); // Chama o método de scrolling
                    posXInicial = e.Location.X + pixels; // Redefine a posição do cursor do mouse em relação à imagem
                }
                else
                {
                    ScrollImg(pixels, Sentido.Esquerda);
                    posXInicial = e.Location.X - pixels;
                }
            }

            if (posYInicial != e.Location.Y)
            {
                if (e.Location.Y > posYInicial)
                {
                    ScrollImg(pixels, Sentido.Baixo);
                    posYInicial = e.Location.Y + pixels;
                }
                else
                {
                    ScrollImg(pixels, Sentido.Cima);
                    posYInicial = e.Location.Y - pixels;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Nota:** Para rolar a imagem ao longo do Panel utilizei o  [ScrollControlIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.scrollcontrolintoview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752970/how-to-programmatically-scroll-a-panel) do SOEN demonstra uma aplicação interessante desse método.